# R/exams exams2blackboard the order of the questions is randomly assigned in the exam

Tags: r-exams, blackboard

I have used `exams2blackboard` to generate an exam and import it into Blackboard. The format of the exam is correct but the order of the questions are shown randomly each time the exam is taken (without selecting that option in Blackboard). How can I avoid that? (I want the questions to appear as they were introduced in the `exams2blackboard` function)

This is my code:

```
exam <- cbind("question1.rmd", "question2.rmd", ...)
                
exams2blackboard(exam,
                 name = "exam",
                 schoice = list(shuffle = FALSE, enumerate = FALSE),
                 eval = list(partial = -33, rule = "false", negative = -100))
```

Comment: Maybe try to use `c()` or `list()` instead of `cbind()` for setting up the exam. Matrix exams are sampled somewhat differently. Maybe that avoids the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I also tried that, but doing that each question is imported in a different pool, which is quite cumbersome and does not solve the problem of the randomization of the questions in the test

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. I'll ask Niels, the main author of `exams2blackboard` to have a look at this.

Comment: In case it helps, I found that the problem is solved by replacing "assessmenttype>Pool" by "assessmenttype>Test" in the res00001.dat file

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the follow-up. I'll mention it to Niels. It should be straightforward to modify that in the `blackboard.xml` template.